# React router nested routes - How to redirect when no route is matching

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm building a web app with three main parts: The actual website, an admin part and a user part. For each part, I want a different layout wrapper.

This is my code right now:

**Website wrapper**

```
const Website = () => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <NavigationBar />
    <main>
      <div className="container">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
          <Route exact path='/login' component={Login}/>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </main>
    <FooterBar />
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

**User wrapper**

```
const User = () => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <UserSideBar />
    <main>
      <div className="container">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/u/dashboard' component={UDashboard}/>
          <Route exact path='/u/account' component={UAccount}/>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </main>
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

**Admin wrapper**

```
const Admin = () => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <main>
    <div className="container">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/a/dashboard' component={ADashboard}/>
        <Route exact path='/a/payments' component={APayments}/>
        <Route exact path='/a/account' component={AAccount}/>
      </Switch>
    </div>
    </main>
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

**Router**

```
const Router = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/u" component={User} />
        <Route path="/a" component={Admin} />
        <Route path="/" component={Website} />

        <Redirect from="*" to="/" />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```

It's all working fine but if an url is not matching any of the routes, it's not redirecting to `'/'`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can add the `Redirect` logic in your `Website` component but this time `/u/foo` or `/a/bar` does not work. I can't find a solution this is why I am going to follow this question :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just make a reusable component ***NoMatch*** and included at the bottom of your `Switch`.
For example:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path='/a/dashboard' component={ADashboard}/>
    <Route exact path='/a/payments' component={APayments}/>
    <Route exact path='/a/account' component={AAccount}/>
    <Route component={Notfound} />
</Switch>
```

**Make sure to put it at the very end** So, if no other route was matched, that one would be displayed.

---

Or you can make a simple custom function which you can reuse depending on your needs:

**You could do this if the undefined path is not clear:**

```
const createRedirect = to => () => <Redirect to={to} />
// ...
<Route path="/*" component={createRedirect('/foo')} />
```

---

To implement a `redirect` ***fallback*** in a *`switch`*, you need to do:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/foo" component={Bar}/>
  <Route path="/bar" component={Baz}/>
  <Route render={() => <Redirect to="/foo"/>}/>
</Switch>
```

---

Or you can take the longer approach and make it programmatically **redirect**. Here is a reference of a reusable component, or at least reusable logic that you could implement to your needs: [Reference](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow)

Comment: I could have sworn that I tried this yesterday both with a NoMatch component and Redirect and couldn't get it worked and surprised. I think I messed up somewhere else. The disadvantage of this method is we need to apply  this logic to each component.